# Django app on heroku shows dyno is up and running, but when I open the app's URL it displays 'Server Error (500)'

Tags: django, heroku

I have been trying to set up my Django app on Heroku for a few days now and seem to have exhausted my searches available to my problem, at least as far as I can tell.

**Problem Summary:** I am able to push my app to Heroku and it seems to work successfully as Heroku confirms it is deployed and the build is successful. But when I try to `heroku open` my app, it returns a server error.

The following is what I do when I encounter the error:

```
git add -A .
git commit -m "initial commit"
heroku create kronos-punch-clock
git push heroku master
```

The above seemed to work correctly and didn't throw any errors.  I then proceeded with:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Heroku replies:

> Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free

```
heroku ps
```

Heroku replies:

> gunicorn kronos_clock.wsgi:application --log-file - (1)    web.1: up
>
> 2016/07/28 17:42:53 -0400 (~20s ago)

I then run:

```
heroku open
```

And alas, I get a: `Server Error(500)` message.

Here are my logs from running `heroku logs`:

> 2016-07-28T21:41:23.094364+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by
>   zz@gmail.com
>
> 2016-07-28T21:41:23.094472+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by
>   zz@gmail.com
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:42.109542+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by
>   zz@gmail.com
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:42.109446+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach DATABASE
>   (@ref:postgresql-cubed-19724) by zz@gmail.com
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:42.660435+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by
>   zz@gmail.com
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:42.661108+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by
>   zz@gmail.com
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:42.661045+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 4935f2a by
>   zz@gmail.com
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:43.215886+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug
>   compilation started
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:43.215897+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug
>   compilation finished
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:49.688459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `gunicorn kronos_clock.wsgi:application --log-file -`
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:52.848547+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-28 21:42:52
>   +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:52.848383+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-28 21:42:52
>   +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:20911 (3)
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:52.953366+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-28 21:42:52
>   +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:52.856553+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-28 21:42:52
>   +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:52.833181+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-28 21:42:52
>   +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
>
> 2016-07-28T21:42:53.445129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to up
>
> 2016-07-28T21:43:16.234692+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/" host=krono-punch-clock.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=943d1695-e12e-4011-8564-b5561859a9da fwd="100.13.50.153"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=69ms status=500 bytes=239
>
> 2016-07-28T21:43:16.387408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/favicon.ico" host=krono-punch-clock.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=857e4d83-7b9d-4a83-aee9-d95976d41146 fwd="100.13.50.153"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=56ms status=404 bytes=285
>
> 2016-07-28T21:43:16.433652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/favicon.ico" host=krono-punch-clock.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=5b298933-0536-48c9-92ba-b4bae7b5b126 fwd="100.13.50.153"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=285

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '29dh!3@ot91d*!60)0x%%9)ndtb)cn#4_uj72=^(@f#h!(fpfc'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #user apps
    'kc_app',

    #third party apps
    'bootstrap3',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kronos_clock.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kronos_clock.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

#settings for django-bootstrap3
BOOTSTRAP3 = {
    'include_jquery':True,
}

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "kronos_clock.settings")

application = DjangoWhiteNoise(get_wsgi_application())
```

**Procfile**

My Procfile is extensionless.

```
web: gunicorn kronos_clock.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

**requirements.txt**

```
dj-database-url==0.4.1
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.9.8
django-bootstrap3==7.0.1
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.6.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
static3==0.7.0
whitenoise==3.2
```

**runtime.txt**

```
python-3.5.1
```

I've been creating this app on Windows 7 too, in case that helps.  Other than that I think this is everything I can think to add for right now, but if any other information is needed please let me know and I will get it posted for you.

**EDIT AND SOLUTION**

Ok, I figured it out.  There were a couple of errors, but I will explain them as best I can in case any one else runs into these same problems.

First off, I was demoing my app locally and wanted to explain the admin site.  When opening it up, it errored and I then remembered I never actually set it up.  this is what was giving the Server Error (500), as it gave this error locally when trying to access the admin site.  I quickly created that and then proceeded below.

In my views.py file I had two assignments to DATABASES.  So, there seemed to be some conflict going on that was causing some errors with Heroku.  It was not necessary for my app to write/save data to the database beyond the current user's instance.  Nevertheless this is what I changed:

I commented out this line:

```
#DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

and switched it to this:

```
if os.getcwd() == "/app":
    DATABASES = {'default':    dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

The if statement allows the app to still be run locally when not running through the Heroku server.

I also had duplicate assignments to DEBUG, although both set to False, I did remove one for clarity's sake and to avoid future change conflicts.

After the DATABASES change above, I also changed DEBUG back to:

```
DEBUG = True
```

I pushed to Heroku and opened the app and fortunately got a helpful error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /
>
> kc_app\base.html
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>     https://krono-punch-clock.herokuapp.com/ Django Version:    1.9.8
>   Exception Type:   TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:
>
> kc_app\base.html
>
> Exception Location:
>     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/engine.py
>   in find_template, line 169 Python Executable:
>     /app/.heroku/python/bin/python Python Version:  3.5.1 Python Path:
>
> ['/app',  '/app/.heroku/python/bin', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-23.1.0-py3.5.egg',
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.5.egg',
>   '/app',  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python35.zip', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/plat-linux', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
>
> Server time:  Sat, 30 Jul 2016 06:33:46 +0000

After some further reading into the traceback I noticed these lines:

> Template-loader postmortem
>
> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
>
> Using engine django:
>
> ```
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/kc_app\base.html
> ```
>
> (Source does not exist)
>       django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/kc_app\base.html
>   (Source does not exist)
>       django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/kc_app/templates/kc_app\base.html (Source does not exist)
>       django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bootstrap3/templates/kc_app\base.html
>   (Source does not exist)

Note here the following line (from above) is where my templates were located:

> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>   /app/kc_app/templates/kc_app\base.html (Source does not exist)

Look very carefully and you will see one backslash instead of a forward slash.  Here I knew it was a Windows difference from the Heroku servers being built on a Nix server and me building the app locally in Windows.  I then changed all my views.py calls and templates to incorporate the forward slash over the backwards slashes.

For examples:

**views.py example**

```
return render(request, 'kc_app\\clock_out.html', 
                         {'kc_form':dict_form,'punch_out':final_out})
```

was changed to:

```
return render(request, 'kc_app/clock_out.html', 
                         {'kc_form':dict_form,'punch_out':final_out})
```

**template example**

{% extends "kc_app\base.html" %}

was changed to:

{% extends "kc_app/base.html" %}

I then pushed the fixes back to Heroku and was able to successfully get it running on the server.

Comment: Try running the app with `DEBUG = True` first.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up following your suggestion along with my above posted edits and was able to solve the problem.